# Why can't I install hashlib with pip in python 3 for Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, hashlib

I tried without success to install hashlib in python 3 for windows with pip.

```
Collecting hashlib
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/bb/9003d081345e9f0451884146e9ea2cff6e4cc4deac9ffd4a9ee98b318a49/hashlib-20081119.zip
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i04d5j03\\hashlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kali\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-i04d5j03\\hashlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\kali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i04d5j03\hashlib\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\kali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i04d5j03\hashlib\
    Complete output (22 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
        import setuptools.version
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
        from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
        from email._policybase import compat32
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
        from email.utils import _has_surrogates
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\email\utils.py", line 28, in <module>
        import random
      File "c:\program files\python36\lib\random.py", line 46, in <module>
        from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
      File "C:\Users\kali\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i04d5j03\hashlib\hashlib.py", line 80
        raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What ca I do?

Answer (score 11):

hashlib is installed in python 2 or python 3 just do import hashlib.

Comment: Thanks a lot for illuminated me. I was trying to install with pip.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [`hashlib` at PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/hashlib/); it's what is installed with `pip install hashlib`. The error message says the code is Python2-only, it uses old `raise` syntax.

The package had [only one release](https://pypi.org/project/hashlib/#history) in 2009. It's obviously too old and abandoned.

You need `hashlib` from [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html).